# How many types may have a variable which been assigned by autoboxed element?

Tags: java

How many types may have i1?

```
? i1 = 1 + "2";
```

I found only two: Object and String. Is it correct? I consider only JDK classes.

Answer (score 5):

There's also  `Comparable<String>`, `CharSequence`, `Serializable`, all the interfaces implemented by `String`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. These all type related to the statement `1 + "2";`.